# git pull results in "fatal: final sha1 did not match"

Tags: git, github

We recently started having a problem with our repo where we get the following error after running `git pull` (technically `git fetch` is what errors). This seems to happen after we merge a remote topic branch in GitHub into our `develop` branch.

Here is the workflow and error:

```
git push origin topic-branch
git checkout develop
git pull
remote: Counting objects: 1, done.
remote: Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (1/1), done.
fatal: final sha1 did not match
fatal: unpack-objects failed
```

I have re-cloned the repo into a new local working copy, went through the same process and got the same error.

What is the cause and what can we do to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use these commands

> [git fsck](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fsck.html)
>
> [git repack](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-repack.html)

If this won't work rm remote and repeat above then add that repo again